# Python numpy exponential notation

Tags: python, numpy

`np.log(someMatrix)` generates values of the type `1.220536239336080619e+01`. I'd like actually see all the digits intead of `+e01`. Is there a way to tell numpy to do so please?

I tried `around()` but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why do you say you're *not* seeing "all the digits"? If you've got huge numbers, don't forget that floating-point numbers have limited precision, so the ones place on an `e+20` float is essentially noise.

Comment: A float double has a max 52 bits of precision, you can check how many you have with something like `len(bin(<int>))` if you print it via. one of the answers suggested below. For example the number in your question would take 63 bits to represent exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see as many digits of a float as you want with a formatted print.
But I agree with user2357112, the last digits may be out of precision limits and are not significant.

```
r=1.220536239336080619e+01
print "%-.24f"%(r)

12.205362393360806194664292
```

Answer (score 1):

when you write your data to file, you can choose between different formattings, `%f` is the one, that don't use exponential notation:

```
np.savetxt('matrix.txt', np.log(someMatrix), '%f')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.array2str` with a formatter that displays it as number without decimals:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1434e24])
np.array2string(a, formatter={'float_kind':lambda x: "%.0f" % x})
# prints '[1433999999999999897558319104]'
```

notice however that the number is dominated by the floating point precision and therefore will not be exactly what you typed in.